# failing unit test for d3.csv() using Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, karma-runner

I am working on an Angular app and I am using Jasmine to write the unit tests and Karma as test runner.

We are using D3 for visualization.

I receive csv data in a file "testData.csv" from a backend service and I use d3.csv("testData.csv") to load the CSV data into a variable, say "data".  Then use, d3.csv.parse(data) to get the JSON array out of CSV data.

I would like to write unit tests for these, but they are failing.  Any help is greatly appreacited.

My Karma conf:

```
    files: [
        'jquery-2.0.3/jquery.js',
        'angular-1.2.4/angular.js',
        'angular-1.2.4/angular-route.js',
        'angular-1.2.4/angular-mocks.js',
        'projectExternal/d3/d3.v3.min.js',  // included D3 library
        'scripts/**/*.js',
        'test/unit/**/*.js'
    ],
```

My Jasmine unit test:

```
    'use strict';

    describe('D3 Page', function () {
        var ctrl = null;
        var scope = null;
        var data;
        var dataJson;

        // load the controller's module
        beforeEach(module('app'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $injector, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('D3Ctrl', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        afterEach(function() {

        });

        it('should parse csv data', function(){
            expect(d3.csv).toBeDefined();  // passes
            d3.csv("testData.csv", function(dataset) {
                console.log("CSV data is: " + dataset); // prints null
                data = dataset;
            });

           console.log(data); // prints null

            var ds = d3.csv.parse(data);
            expect(ds.length).toBe(3);   // prints ds.length = 0, fails Expected 0 to be 3
    //      console.log(ds); // prints null

        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if its a typo in the question, but you're missing a `'` character after the `'scripts/**/*.js,` line in your karma config file.

Comment: yes, that was a typo, corrected it.

Comment: I wonder if d3.csv(PATH) **can't** see the file since you're running through node. Can you try putting the file in a particular folder and referencing it with an absolute path? Like `/users/joe/testData.csv`?

Comment: I tried that as well, but no luck. I tried using absolute path on my laptop like /Users/vd/testData.csv, it didn't work and got the same result.

Comment: is the CSV valid? Try running it through http://csvlint.io/

Comment: just ran it through csvlint.io and i got below message. CSV is valid.                                                              Structural problem: Non-standard Line Breaks

Your CSV appears to use LF line-breaks. While this will be fine in most cases, RFC 4180 specifies that CSV files should use CR-LF (a carriage-return and line-feed pair, e.g. \r\n). This may be labelled as "Windows line endings" on some systems.

Answer (score 2):

`d3.csv` is asynchronous, so you need to handle it that way.

Try something like this:

```
it('should parse csv data', function(){
    expect(d3.csv).toBeDefined();    // passes
    d3.csv("/absolute/path/to/testData.csv", function(error, dataset) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        } else {
            console.log("Data: " + data);
        }
        console.log("CSV data is: " + dataset); // prints null
        data = dataset;
        console.log(data);           // prints null
        var ds = d3.csv.parse(data);
        expect(ds.length).toBe(3);   // prints ds.length = 0, fails Expected 0 to be 3
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Paul. I tried your suggestion and test still fails.  I got the following response                                            'Error: [object XMLHttpRequest]'
'CSV data is: undefined'
undefined
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'n.length')

Comment: Try the same test with a simpler CSV file. I think the problem is in the file.

Comment: I am using the same csv for the actual code which works flawlessly. It's only the unit test I am having issues with.